# How to select main stream with ffprobe

Tags: ffprobe

When doing automated work with ffmpeg/ffprobe, I tend to just select the first stream of video and ignore the rest. Today I bumped into a file where the first video stream has no frames, but the second one does.

Is there a way to reliably know which stream should be selected? I suppose I could look at the number of frames, but I see things like "profile=Main" vs "profile=Baseline", or "level=-99" vs "level=40" and I wonder if those, or some different key, are better indicators.

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=mjpeg
codec_long_name=Motion JPEG
profile=Baseline
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=0/1
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=800
height=450
coded_width=800
coded_height=450
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
display_aspect_ratio=N/A
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
level=-99
color_range=pc
color_space=bt470bg
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=center
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=90000/1
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=58094107
duration=645.490078
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=1
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=Main
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=7745881/464208000
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1280
height=720
coded_width=1280
coded_height=720
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
display_aspect_ratio=N/A
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=40
color_range=unknown
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=179/6
avg_frame_rate=232104000/7745881
time_base=1/60000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=38729405
duration=645.490083
bit_rate=20005057
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=19342
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:creation_time=2022-02-20T16:07:45.000000Z
TAG:language=und
[/STREAM]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first video stream is a single image artwork. Such streams have at least one of the following two dispositions set.

Compare

```
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=1
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
```

vs.

```
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
```

Second place is to look at the average frame rate.

Compare

```
avg_frame_rate=0/0
```

vs.

```
avg_frame_rate=232104000/7745881
```